# Logical Error while using ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> collection framework

Tags: java, arraylist

I am learning to use Collections in java. I made a simple program in which I want the output to be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3]]
[5, 6, 7]
[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Instead of getting the above output I am getting the output as:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[[1, 2, 3]]
[5, 6, 7]
[[5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]]
```

i.e each time I add one more ArrayList the new is added but the previous one gets replaced by the new one too. I don't want it to get replaced. Can anyone explain me whats going on in here? My code is:

```
import java.util.*;

class Amit{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    b.add(1);
    b.add(2);
    b.add(3);

    System.out.println(b);
    a.add(b);
    System.out.println(a);

    b.clear();

    b.add(5);
    b.add(6);
    b.add(7);

    System.out.println(b);
    a.add(b);
    System.out.println(a);

}
}
```

Comment: You are treating b as a primitive type, when it is an object. When you change b to become [5,6,7], it becomes [5,6,7] in both places, since it is the same object.

Comment: @Gendarme Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`a` has a reference to the list `b`. It is a reference and not a copy. So if you clear `b`, all the values in `a` gets emptied. Then you add 5,6,7 and add id again.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

b.add(1);
b.add(2);
b.add(3);

System.out.println(b);
a.add(b);  // a= [[1,2,3]]
System.out.println(a);

b.clear();  // a = [[]]

b.add(5); //a = [[5]]
b.add(6); // a=[[5,6]]
b.add(7); // a=[[5,6,7]]

System.out.println(b);
a.add(b); //a=[[5,6,7],[5,6,7]]
System.out.println(a);
```

}